# How to set the Bluetooth device automatically connect in Android(Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

**BleActivity.kt**

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class BleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
    private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null

    private val REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL = 2
    private val PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )

    private var scanning: Boolean = false
    private var deviceArr = ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()
    private val SCAN_PERIOD = 1000
    private val handler = Handler()

    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter

    private var bleGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
    private var mContext: Context? = null

    private val serviceUUID = UUID.fromString("55e405d2-af9f-a98f-e54a-7dfe43535355")
    private val characteristicUUID = UUID.fromString("16962447-c623-61ba-d94b-4d1e43535349")

    private val mLeScanCallback = @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            Log.d("scanCallback", "BLE Scan Failed: ${errorCode}")
        }

        override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results)
            results?.let {
                for (result in it) {
                    if (!deviceArr.contains(result.device) && result.device.name != null) {
                        deviceArr.add(result.device)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            result?.let {
                if (!deviceArr.contains(it.device) && it.device.name != null) {
                    deviceArr.add(it.device)
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun scanDevice(state: Boolean) = if (state) {
        handler.postDelayed({
            scanning = false
            bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(mLeScanCallback)
        }, SCAN_PERIOD)
        scanning = true
        deviceArr.clear()
        bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(mLeScanCallback)
    } else {
        scanning = false
        bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(mLeScanCallback)
    }

    private fun hasPermissions(context: Context?, permissions: Array<String>): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (permission in permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        permission
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String?>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions must be granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble)

        mContext = this

        val bluetooth_button: ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_btn)
        val scan_button: Button = findViewById(R.id.scan_button)

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(deviceArr)
        recyclerViewAdapter.mListener = object : RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                scanDevice(false)
                val device = deviceArr.get(position)
                bleGatt = DeviceControlActivity(mContext, bleGatt).connectGatt(device)

                // Dialog 띄우는 코드 추가
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_wifimanager, null)
                val ble_ssid = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ble_ssid)
                val ble_pw = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ble_pw)

                val wifiManager =
                    mContext?.applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
                val ssid = wifiInfo.ssid.replace("\"", "")

                ble_ssid.text = ssid

                builder.setView(dialogView)
                    .setPositiveButton("연결") { dialog, _ ->
                        // 연결 확인 버튼을 누른 경우의 동작 추가

                        val send_ssid = ble_ssid.text.toString()
                        val send_pw = ble_pw.text.toString()
                        val SP = ","
                        val CR = "\r"
                        val LF = "\n"

                        val sumData = send_ssid + SP + send_pw + CR + LF
                        val result = sumData.toByteArray()

                        val service = bleGatt?.getService(serviceUUID)
                        val characteristic = service?.getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID)

                        if (result.size <= 20) { // 20바이트 이하일 때는 그대로 송신
                            characteristic?.value = result
                            bleGatt?.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
                        } else { // 20바이트보다 크면 패킷으로 분할하여 여러 번 송신
                            val numPackets = (result.size + 19) / 20 // 전체 패킷 개수 계산
                            for (i in 0 until numPackets) { // 패킷 단위로 분할하여 여러 번 송신
                                val packetSize =
                                    if (i < numPackets - 1) 20 else result.size % 20 // 패킷 크기 계산
                                val packet =
                                    result.copyOfRange(i * 20, i * 20 + packetSize) // 패킷 복사
                                characteristic?.value = packet
                                bleGatt?.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
                                Thread.sleep(10) // 패킷 간 간격을 두어 충돌을 방지합니다.
                            }
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("취소") { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        // 취소 버튼을 누른 경우의 동작 추가
                    }
                    .show()
            }
        }

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView?>(R.id.recyclerView).apply {
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
        }.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
                bluetooth_button.isChecked = true
                scan_button.isVisible = false
            } else {
                bluetooth_button.isChecked = false
                scan_button.isVisible = true
            }
        }

        bluetooth_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            bluetoothOnOff()
            scan_button.visibility = if (scan_button.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                View.INVISIBLE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }

            if (scan_button.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
                scanDevice(false)
                deviceArr.clear()
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

        scan_button.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
            if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL)
            }
            scanDevice(true)
        }
    }

    fun bluetoothOnOff() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d("bluetoothAdapter", "Device doesn't support Bluetooth")
        } else {
            if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
                val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
            } else {
                bluetoothAdapter?.disable()
            }
        }
    }

    class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

        var mListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

        interface OnItemClickListener {
            fun onClick(view: View, position: Int)
        }

        class MyViewHolder(val linearView: LinearLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(linearView)

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val linearView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
                    as LinearLayout
            return MyViewHolder(linearView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val itemName: TextView = holder.linearView.findViewById(R.id.item_name)
            val itemAddress: TextView = holder.linearView.findViewById(R.id.item_address)
            itemName.text = myDataset[position].name
            itemAddress.text = myDataset[position].address
            if (mListener != null) {
                holder?.linearView?.setOnClickListener { v ->
                    mListener?.onClick(v, position)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = myDataset.size
    }
}

private fun Handler.postDelayed(function: () -> Unit, scanPeriod: Int) {}
```

**DeviceControlActivity.kt**

```
private val TAG = "gattClienCallback"

class DeviceControlActivity(
    private val context: Context?,
    private var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt?
) {
    private var device: BluetoothDevice? = null
    private val gattCallback: BluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            when (newState) {
                BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.")
                    Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "Attempting to start service discovery: ${bluetoothGatt?.discoverServices()}"
                    )
                    gatt?.discoverServices()
                }
                BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected to GATT server.")
                    disconnectGattServer()
                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT_SUCCESS")
                    broadcastUpdate("Connected ${device?.name}")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Device service discovery failed, status: ${status}")
                    broadcastUpdate("Fail Connect ${device?.name}")
                }
            }
        }

        private fun broadcastUpdate(str: String) {
            val mHandler: Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg)
                    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            mHandler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget()
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private fun disconnectGattServer() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Closing Gatt connection")
            if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
                bluetoothGatt?.disconnect()
                bluetoothGatt?.close()
                bluetoothGatt = null
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun connectGatt(device: BluetoothDevice): BluetoothGatt? {
        this.device = device

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            bluetoothGatt =
                device.connectGatt(context, true, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
        } else {
            bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, true, gattCallback)
        }
        return bluetoothGatt
    }
}
```

for this code is need to pressed the 2 button(bluetooth_button, scan_button) then can search the bluetooth device and connect the bluetooth device.

So my problem is how to write the code to let it automatically connect the bluetooth device after search the device mean that I no need to pressed any button just select the device then it can auto connect the device that I have select.

I am new in Android of BLE. Please help to find the solution. Thank You